# How to convert 10 bytes to a number uint16 and to restore an array from a number

Tags: algorithm, go, math

I try to accommodate two addresses and a port in an array and then, as seen by the code, convert to uint16 for further work, but I do not get the desired result at the output.
I know that I only have 4 bytes in my code, and 10 need to be reversed.

```
 s, d := net.IP{172, 16, 100, 11}, net.IP{10, 0, 88, 11}
 var sp uint16 = 54876
 //var dp uint16 = 445

 var spByte = make([]byte, 2)
 binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(spByte, sp)

 var x = make([]byte, 10) // [172 16 100 11 10 0 88 11 214 92]
 copy(x[:4], s)
 copy(x[4:], d)
 copy(x[8:], spByte)

 ret := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(x)

 var a, z uint16
 a = uint16(ret >> 16)
 z = uint16(ret & 0xFFFF)

 newret := (uint32(a) << 16) | uint32(z)


 var xs = make([]byte,10) // [172 16 100 11 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(xs,newret)
```

I am trying to get a number from an array [172 16 100 11 10 0 88 11 214 92] and then restore the given array from the same number.

Comment: I don't understand your question. First, you cannot "convert" an IP address, let alone two, plus ports, into a uint16. One IP address is 32 bytes, a port is an additional 16 bytes. Two of those, naturally, requires 96 bytes, not 16.

Comment: Second, and probably more important, you haven't stated what help you need. What problem do you observe in your code? What help do you need solving it?

Comment: @Flimzy 
I try to convert an array to a number, then use bitwise shift to make it uint16 and turn it into an array in the reverse order, and if it’s concrete, my task is to pack source ip and source port into one number and get source again from this number ip and source port

Comment: It's logically impossible to convert 96 bits of data into 16 bits, without discarding 80 bits of information. Bitwise shift or no.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to pack and unpack the values from a slice of bytes:

```
s, d := net.IP{172, 16, 100, 11}, net.IP{10, 0, 88, 11}
var sp uint16 = 54876

var x = make([]byte, 10) // [172 16 100 11 10 0 88 11 214 92]
copy(x[:4], s)
copy(x[4:], d)
binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(x[8:], sp)

s2 := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(x)
d2 := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(x[4:])
sp2 := binary.BigEndian.Uint16(x[8:])

fmt.Printf("s: %x %x\n", []byte(s), s2)
fmt.Printf("d: %x %x\n", []byte(d), d2)
fmt.Printf("sp: %d %d\n", sp, sp2)
```

Try it on the GoLang PlayGround: https://play.golang.org/p/MFzdVtyoBsm